# replacing text with merge field Docx4j

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, ms-word, docx4j

I am trying to replace a text with a placeholder (merge-field) using Docx4j. Suppose I submit a form with text "Dear [firstName] ,...". I need to create a word document using the text submitted from the form while replacing the "[firstName]" with merge-field.

I am currently finding the text between "[" and "]" using regular expression and creating a merge field for that using docx4j:

```
    String regex = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(eachSplit);

    while(m.find()) {

        ctSimple.setInstr(" MergeField "+m.group(1)+" \\* MERGEFORMAT ");

        RPr RPr = factory.createRPr();
        RPr.setNoProof(new BooleanDefaultTrue());

        Text t = factory.createText();
        t.setValue("<"+m.group(1)+">");

        R run = factory.createR();
        run.getContent().add(RPr);
        run.getContent().add(t);

        ctSimple.getContent().add(run);

    }
    JAXBElement<CTSimpleField> fldSimple = factory.createPFldSimple(ctSimple);
```

So what I want now is to be able to replace the text "[firstName]" with "fldSimple" merge field.

I could add the merge field at the end of the paragraph like this:

```
P para = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText(newPara);
para.getContent().add(fldSimple);
```

But I don't know how to add the merge field on the same location as the found text. I found out that may be I could use some xpath to do this as shown in the [forum](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/replace-text-with-paragraph-t912.html) but I do not fully grasp the concept.

I know that if the generated xml for this looks something like:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Dear [lastName],</w:t>
     </w:r>
  </w:p>
```

I need to change this to:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Dear</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
      <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:fldSimple w:instr=" MERGEFIELD  lastName  \* MERGEFORMAT ">
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof/>
       </w:rPr>
     <w:t>«lastName»</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:fldSimple>
   <w:r>
   <w:t>,</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

How can I achieve this?